# Javascript closure : Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, closures

I have a memory leak I don't understand. I programmed a mechanism to handle event with semi-automatically unbinding which should allow me to clean up memory easily.
But in one case, the clean up doesn't happen (I use chrome's "profile (memory heap)" to check for instances of "EventHandler" left). I really don't get why it happen. There's something weird with the closure...

[see it in action with chrome](http://serge.snakeman.be/Demo/test.html)

```
function Bind(obj, f) {
    return function() {
        return f.apply(obj, arguments);
    }
}

function EventHandler() {
    this.listeners = new Object();

    var _listenerID = 0;
    this.addListener = function(e, obj, listener, specialDisplay) {
        if (typeof(listener) === "function") {
            var listenerID = ++_listenerID;
            console.log("Events (" + (++EventHandler.All) + ", " + listenerID + ") ++" + e);

            if (!this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
                this.listeners[e] = new Object();
            }
            this.listeners[e][listenerID] = listener;

            if (obj != null && typeof(obj.removeListener) == "function") {
                var deleteListenerID = obj.addListener("Delete", null, Bind(this, function() {
                    this.removeListener(e, listenerID);
                    obj.removeListener("Delete", deleteListenerID);
                }));
            }

            return listenerID;
        }

        return null;
    }
    this.fire = function(e, obj) {
        if (this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
            for(var i in this.listeners[e]) {
                this.listeners[e][i](obj);
            }
        }
    }
    this.removeListener = function(e, listenerID) {
        if (this.listeners.hasOwnProperty(e) && this.listeners[e].hasOwnProperty(listenerID)) {
            delete this.listeners[e][listenerID];

            console.log("Events (" + (--EventHandler.All) + ", " + listenerID + ") --" + e);
        }
    }
}

EventHandler.All = 0;

function Loader() {
}

Loader.files = new Object();

Loader.LoadImage = function(src, f) {
    if (!Loader.files.hasOwnProperty(src)) {
        var handler = new EventHandler();

        console.log("Loading.... (" + src + ")");

        Loader.files[src] = function(fnct) {
            handler.addListener("ImageLoaded", handler, function(img) {
                fnct(img);
            });
        }

        handler.addListener("ImageLoaded", handler, function() {
            Loader.files[src] = function(fnct) {
                fnct(img);
            }
        });     

        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function() {
            console.log("Loaded.... (" + src + ")");
            handler.fire("ImageLoaded", img);
            handler.fire("Delete");
            $(img).unbind('load');
        });
        img.src = src;
    }

    Loader.files[src](f);
}

Loader.LoadImage("http://serge.snakeman.be/Demo/house.jpg", function() { alert("ok"); });
```

Comment: Could you please do as the error message says and paste the code from jsfiddle to the question. Thanks.

Comment: I really don't know what part of the code would be the more meaningful I was actually a bit disconcerted by the stackoverflow warning.

Comment: If somebody could upvote my question, I'll grant a 50 bounty for the answer...

Comment: I though 50 rep wxas sufficient, I just read it is 75. I guess I'll have to wait longer to get an answer.

Comment: The bounty didn't help yet :(

Comment: Doesn't you "Bind" method creates a new anonymous function everytime you call it. Thus, each time you add a listener, you add a new anonymous function as Listener. That disturbs me since theoritically the .removeListener method needs as parameters the target, and the listener function (the exact same object). Couldn't it be a first issue ? Furthermore you use "deleteListenerID" before initializing it no ? It's the function's return AND a variable used inside this same function

Comment: I don't use "deleteListenerID" before initializing it. It's initialized by the addListener call and used later on whenever the "Delete event" is called on the object. The Bind is required to have this = "current this" and it doesn't cause trouble since the whole function get deleted at some point anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You create closures that hold a reference to an `EventHandler` instance via the `handler` variable. One of the closures remains after the image has been loaded:

```
    handler.addListener("ImageLoaded", handler, function() {
        Loader.files[src] = function(fnct) {
            fnct(img);
        }
    });
```

It's the inner function `function(fnct) {...`. The instance of `EventHandler` cannot be freed as long as the closure exists. Your only solution is to get rid of that closure. Or you free the instance manually, if possible. The following might work for you:

```
handler.fire("Delete");
handler = undefined;
```

Chrome's memory profiler shows you the object's retaining tree, which is just another way to say "Who is holding a reference that object". In your example it's **EventHandler** <- **handler** (the variable of the LoadImage method as incorporated by the closure) <- **house.jpg**, which actually is `Loader.files[src]` and has the value `function(fnct) { fnct(img); }`.

Comment: When the image gets loaded the reference hold in Loader.files[src] is dropped since I set it to another value.

Loader.files[src] = function(fnct) {
                fnct(img);
            }

Comment: You are right, of course, I missed that. But that does not change much: this function prevents the EventHandler instance from being released (says the profiler). I am not a 100% sure, but afaik as long as a function exists, that could reference the handler variable, the EventHandler instance won't be released.

Comment: What do you suggest is made for the function not to exist anymore? I don't get where it could be hold anyway. :S

Comment: That should solve the problem. The thing is that you seem to need this function. It is called when `Loader.LoadImage` is called for an already loaded image.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting your solution. Mind to write the full code, please?

Comment: The solution would be to remove `Loader.files[src] = function(fnct) { fnct(img); }`, since this creates a closure. You could for instance replace it with `Loader.files[src] = f` and either not call f with `img` as argument or store the reference to the image somewhere else. E.g. `Loader.files[src].callback = f; ... Loader.files[src].img = new Image(); ... Loader.files[src].callback(Loader.files[src].img);`

Comment: I added a simpler possible solution to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

While you are adding 'listeners' make sure you are removing it, if you are using the query for long time.

```
this.listeners = new Object();
```

or

```
this.listeners[e] = new Object();
```

this will add object to listener as array, but not removing them at any point.

This may be the reason for Memory Consumption. It may not leak, its assignment of objects. that consumes your RAM using browser. :)

Comment: I'm removing them. On to the console you can see "Events (0, 4) --Delete" which indicate the last remaining listener has been removed.

Comment: Its general practice when you are dealing with listeners in system.

You need to handle them including removing them. The same apply to browser in some cases :) If you are removing them then its out of my reach. but for double check, check the element in console 'listeners[]'. Whether it have elements or not.

Comment: Adding object to the console, makes chrome hold another reference on them. But since you're just talking about the listeners[] is shouldn't hurt trying (I'll try this evening).